# JavaScript doesn't work in my frames?

Tags: javascript, passwords, frameset

I am making a homepage at the moment and I have made an edge around the "main page" with frameset... that was probably stupid, but now my JavaScript for some reason doesn't work?!

What I want to do is make a username and password protected page using javascript. The script itself is as follows:

`function logIn(); {`

```
var username = prompt("Skriv venligst dit brugernavn:" , "");

var password = prompt("Skriv venligst dit password:" , "");

var PassWords = new Array(46);
{
    PassWords[0] = "username:password";
    PassWords[1] = "username1:password1";
    PassWords[2] = "and_so_on:and_so_on";
}

for (i = 0; i < PassWords.length; i++)
{
    if (PassWords[i].indexOf(username) == 0)
    {
        var Split = koder[i].split(":");
        var UserName = Split[0];
        var PassWord = Split[1];
        if (username == UserName && password == PassWord)
        {
            alert("Access Granted")
            window.location="access.htm";
        }
        else 
        {
            alert("Access Denied!")
            window.location="no_access.htm";
        }
    }
}
```

}

Please help me!! (: The link to the homepage is http://www.vestervang-dejret.dk/ - you probably won't understand it because it's danish but hover "Dokumenter" and select "Referater" and if you click the button you will see nothing happens... I've tried triggering the script with a button and the onload-event but nothing works! PLEASE HELP!

Comment: Why bother with the authentication code at all? Anybody that knows about the "View source" feature of their browser could circumvent this security in a few seconds.

Comment: I know - but amateurs wouldn't think of it... I hope :O
I am rather new at this whole programming thing (as you can see, I obviously made a rookie-mistake) so I would appreciate it if you could name another way of "securing" your homepages? :)

Comment: It depends on what technology you're using on the server. Look into sessions: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_(computer_science)

Comment: @Lasse Herold: Security by obscurity is no security at all. Even someone with basic HTML knowledge and no programming or hacking experience should be able to hack this site without breaking a sweat. You need to do the authentication checks server-side, not client side.

Comment: @Lasse Herold: Actually, now that I think about it. You wouldn't even need to attempt to hack this site. Google will index even the secured pages and link directly to them. So people would just need to Google any word on the secured part of the site and click on the search result to circumvent your security.

Comment: All that aside, what if you've 1000 users - are you gonna put the user names and passwords of all those users in the html? If you put this code in a production code, it'll end up in http://thedailywtf.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the semicolon ";" after login()

JavaScript is seeing that as the end of statement, and not taking into account the function body. It's still valid JavaScript, but it's not a function definition.

```
function logIn() {

 var username = prompt("Skriv venligst dit brugernavn:" , "");

var password = prompt("Skriv venligst dit password:" , "");
// ... etc...
```